# AWS Endpoint Error When Uploading Files Using Paperclip Deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-web-services, paperclip

When I upload an image using Paperclip on Heroku, it uploads the image as http://s3.amazonaws.com/moviereviewnd/movies/images/000/000/005/small/wolf_of_wall_street_ver3_xxlg.jpeg?1424809711

Note:  It uploads fine on local server (Ubuntu 14.04).  I've tried everything I can find on this site and nothing seems to work.  The Bucket is definitely not a Eurpoean bucket or anything like that.  I chose Oregon and when I log into AWS, it says https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?**region=us-west-2**

When you visit the image URL posted above, it says "The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.".  It also says when you visit the above URL that the endpoint is:

moviereviewnd.s3.amazonaws.com

Any ideas?  I've been stuck on this for hours and cannot seem to figure it out.

In my config/environments/production.rb, I currently have this:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  :region => 'us-west-2',
  :s3_endpoint => 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
}
}
```

But have also tried this:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  :region => 'us-west-2',
  :s3_endpoint => 'moviereviewnd.s3.amazonaws.com'
}
}
```

Both ways result in the same URL mentioned at the top of this post and lead to the "must be addressed using the specified endpoint" message.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails',                '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.1'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.13.4'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: Note: Image uploads fine (no error) and uploads the AWS, but image is not displayed due to the URL used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woohoo!  Using :s3_host_name instead of :s3_endpoint worked!

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :region => 'us-west-2',
      :s3_host_name => 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
      :url => ":s3_domain_url"
    }
```